# MongoDB (pymongo). Replace all blank strings with null

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to figure a quick way to replace blank strings ('') that I have in a lot of my documents (across many fields) with MongoDB's null value.

In MongoDB docs, I was hoping to use ReplaceAll, but I can't figure out how to execute the same thing in pymongo unless I do replace_one().

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can use the Collection's `update_many` method for this purpose. I guess you need to specify all the fields that requires the update - both in the query filter and the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `pymongo` does not support replace all. Most effective way to update many documents would be `update_many`.
It looks something like this:

```
db.my_db.update_many(
    filter={'field_1': ""},
    update={'$set': {'field_1': None}}
)
```